# Can't call a deployed contract method

Tags: contract-invocation, ethers.js

I am trying to connect to the Pangolin DEX (a Uniswap fork) on the Avalanche Fuji testnet (Avalance uses EVM). With this:

```
import console from "console";
const ethers = require("ethers");

async function main(){

    // url is to a free shared Avalanche node on the Fuji testnet from Chainstack. It does work.
    var urlInfo = {url: 'https://nd-211-849-225.p2pify.com/nope/ext/bc/C/rpc'};
    const provider = new ethers.providers.StaticJsonRpcProvider(urlInfo, 43113);
    const block = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    console.log("Block Number is " + block); // block does have a value

    const PangolinFactory = "0xefa94DE7a4656D787667C749f7E1223D71E9FD88";
    
    const pangolinFactoryABI = [
        "function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair)",
        "function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair)",
        "function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint)"
    ];
    
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(PangolinFactory, pangolinFactoryABI, provider);
    console.log(await contract.allPairsLength());
}

main();
```

The provider is connecting as it should, but the call to `allPairsLength` (or any method I try) always results in a `CALL_EXCEPTION`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a [non-existent contract](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0xefa94DE7a4656D787667C749f7E1223D71E9FD88) on the Fuji testnet, while the contract you specify is [on the mainnet](https://snowtrace.io/address/0xefa94DE7a4656D787667C749f7E1223D71E9FD88). You need to swap your Chainstack RPC endpoint from the Fuji one to the mainnet one.